# how can i add NFC intent in .NET MAUI?

Tags: c#, android, .net, nfc, maui

I'm developing an application which scans NFC tags (using Plugin.NFC) and does something from them. I should have 2 pages where I can scan NFC tags but It works only in one of the 2 pages. I think that maybe it can be a problem with intent in my MainActivity.cs. This is the code of my MainActivity.cs:

```
using Android.App;
    using Android.Content;
    using Android.Content.PM;
    using Android.Nfc;
    using Android.OS;
    using Plugin.NFC;

namespace ParcoDelCurone;

[Activity(Theme = "@style/Maui.SplashTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Density)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { NfcAdapter.ActionNdefDiscovered }, Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault }, DataMimeType = MainPage.MIME_TYPE)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { NfcAdapter.ActionTagDiscovered }, Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault }, DataMimeType = MainPage.MIME_TYPE)]

public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        CrossNFC.Init(this);
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        CrossNFC.OnResume();
    }

    protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        base.OnNewIntent(intent);
        CrossNFC.OnNewIntent(intent);
    }
}
```

I tried to solve it using always the same page but it doesn't work.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to scan an NFC tag and i want to use the message from NFC to open a new page